# Powershell convertfrom-json add value's and convertto-json

Tags: json, powershell, addition, edit

```
$json = @"{"mem":[[1377691200,10],[1377770400,0]],"proc":[[1377691200,80],[1377770400,0]]}"@
$jobj = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $json
$datetime = 1377780400
$proc = 85
$add = @($datetime, $proc)
$jobj.proc += $($add)
cls
ConvertTo-Json $jobj
```

The snippet above should add a array value to the json string but is seems to add to seperate values.

In the result the added values dont have [] and if i goto $jobj.proc[3] and [4] the values are split out of there original array. What can i do to fix this?

I found question [PowerShell how to add something on parsed JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720045/powershell-how-to-add-something-on-parsed-json)

But i dont have names for my entries so that wont work :(

Any clues

Comment: to test hit enter after @" and before "@ in the json string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
$json = '{"mem":[[1377691200,10],[1377770400,0]],"proc":[[1377691200,80],[1377770400,0]]}'
$jobj = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $json
$datetime = 1377780400
$proc = 85
$add = @($datetime, $proc)
$jobj.proc += ,$add
cls
ConvertTo-Json $jobj
```

Adding the leading comma in the += operation prevents "unrolling" the $add array.

Comment: Welcome! Now it won't be rolling around in your head while you're trying to get to sleep :)